# i18next : Object [object Object] has no method 'i18n'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, i18next

I'm trying to use i18next.js with backbone.js but I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'i18n'

Here is my html :

```
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-i18n="menu.surname"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-i18n="menu.firstName"></a></li>

</ul>
</body>
```

here is my locales/en/translation.json :

```
{
"menu": {
"surname": "Name:",
"firstName": "First Name:"
}}
```

and here is my translation.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
language = "en";

i18n.init({ lng: language, debug: true }, function(t) {
    $(".menu").i18n();
});
});
```

For now there is no langage detection , I only use "en" in static but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: http://i18next.com/pages/doc_jquery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. I was loading jquery twice , so when the second jquery was loaded it unload every jquery plugins.